# Check for value in MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, pdo

I am storing user ID values in a table field separated by a | (user_id1|user_id2|user_id3|user_id17).

A user ID will be added and removed from this field at certain points.

How can I check if the current users ID exists in the field or not using a query?
And it of course needs to be an exact match. Can't look for `user_id1` and find `user_id17`.

I know I could use a SELECT query, explode the field, then use `in_array` but if there's a way to do it using a query it'd be better.

Comment: this is wrong way of storing ids. store them in a separate table.

Comment: Two last IDs in your sample are separated by a comma (`,`).

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's the proper way for what I am doing. Thanks for your concern and downvote though.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment that this is a bad database design. If, however, you absolutely have to have multiple IDs in the same column, then have delimiter after each of them (even the *last* one). This way you can search for `ID+"|"`.

Comment: @Draven it is not the proper way. you might think it is because you want to do it, but you should use a relational database and use proper database theory. Let the database engine do the work, not an external program.

Comment: You other option is to use **Regular Expressions** and search for the exact ID terminated with the delimiter or end of string.

Comment: @Hiroto I guess I'll explain what I am doing: I made a forum for a small private website (7 users), but coding it for larger scale. What I am seeking help on is to mark Topics as unread for each user. I could create a new table with topic_id & user_id, each one being a new row but that wouldn't be good with alot of users & topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing your values for a forum for users who have not yet read the topic (which is a bad idea) is not going to be scalable.
Do it *the other way around* if you really have to, since you'll also have the issues associated with having to add entries to **every topic in your database** upon a new user signup.

Instead of foregoing a relational table, try instead doing it as follows:<sup>1</sup>

```
Table: topics
+----+-------+------+-----
| id | title | body | ...
+----+-------+------+-----
| 1  | xyz   | .... | ...

Table: replies
+----+-------+------+-----
| id | title | body | ...
+----+-------+------+-----
| 3  | xyz   | .... | ...

Table: read_topics
+---------+----------+
| user_id | topic_id |
+---------+----------+
| 2       | 1        |
```

Your approach, while possible (and easier to imagine) starts to break down when you have massive amounts of users, and scalability is what you alluded to in the comments. Another problem here is that with your approach, you have **massive** performance penalties because you have to pull the data from the database, split it, and then manipulate and re-combine, before making another transaction. You also have issues with ***having the table being written to by two CGI threads at the same time***. Have fun with that...

You are using a tool for data manipulation, sorting, data relationships, and storage, so use it for all of them, not just as a dumping ground for information.

<sup>1. I am far from a complete expert on database optimization, and there's very likely a better way than this. Test!</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this. This is the way I am going to do it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you don't need arrays in your database. The database already has arrays and they are called tables. Use them.

Comment: @siride good point! (and regarding your edit, I feel embarrassed for that. ._.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to store id's in this fashion. A better strategy would be to refactor this column into another table and store one row per user_id in that table.

In any case, If you can slightly alter the way you are storing user_ids in the column by always beginning and ending the content with a  "|",

For example, change this:

```
(user_id1|user_id2|user_id3|user_id17)
```

to

```
(|user_id1|user_id2|user_id3|user_id17|)
```

Then your query becomes simple

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename WHERE userid_csv LIKE "%|user_id1|%"
```

Note that this can be highly inefficient and may result in table sweeps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the MySQL equivalent of [Postgres arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html). It warrants an upvote, as it's a reasonable way to approach the problem you describe. Unfortunately, until MySQL supports array-type data, you might have to resort to a hinky string-to-array process as you describe. I would do some research into others' solutions to setting up array-type values and relations in MySQL. I would also try to do some testing on a massive data set with the type of data you expect to see if this would actually be an optimization, or if you would be better off with a more standard solution using an intersection table.

The other thought that comes to mind without seeing your data is to create an intersection table with topic ids & user ids, but only insert a row when a topic is read. Then you can assume the lack of a row for a user/topic indicates 'unread'.

Comment: How about using proper normalization? What's so hard about that? Putting array types into fields violates basic principles of database design.

Comment: As I said, I would do performance testing on an intersection table before trying this approach. The only reason I would consider this approach is if the intersection table became too large and unwieldy (which is why I proposed a solution to limit the size of the intersection table).  I do expect more RDBMS's to start supporting array data types, which can be a nice balance between strict relational patterns and a NoSQL approach. Postgres will soon support referential integrity on arrays used as foreign keys: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys.

Comment: How could the intersection table be more unwieldy than multi-valued data packed into columns? The former use an existing, well-understood model that is consistent with the structure of the rest of the database. The latter add a new model and structure which will most likely take additional syntax and processing time.

Comment: I should clarify: I am not advocating the use of arrays as foreign keys; my proposed solution was essentially the same as the accepted answer, which was to use a standard intersection table with a limited amount of data. However, I didn't think the question deserved a downvote, as it isn't completely out of left field. There is a reason this question comes up frequently, and there is a reason that NoSQL solutions are increasingly popular. I'm just picturing a scenario when one or more of the tables and their indexes become too large for the hardware to handle efficiently...[cont.]

Comment: [cont.]At that point, any system is going to have to rely on an added layer of complexity, whether it be sharding, partitioning, or whatever extra voodoo is available to the RDBMS involved. The SQL standard already allows array datatypes, although MySQL has yet to catch up (hence my recommendation to do some performance testing, which I have no doubt would lead down the well-trodden path to an intersection table).  However, in a database that allows array storage, there could easily be performance gains in dealing with two rather than three tables. Time permitting, I'll post some test numbers.