# Check for value in CSV MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, pdo

I am storing user ID values in a table field separated by a | (user_id1|user_id2|user_id3|user_id17).

A user ID will be added and removed from this field at certain points.

How can I check if the current users ID exists in the field or not using a query?
And it of course needs to be an exact match. Can't look for `user_id1` and find `user_id17`.

I know I could use a SELECT query, explode the field, then use `in_array` but if there's a way to do it using a query it'd be better.

I guess I'll explain what I am doing: I made a forum for a small private website (7 users), but coding it for larger scale.

My table structure is pretty good: forum_categories, forum_topics, forum_posts. Using foreign keys between the tables for delete and update queries.

What I am seeking help on is to mark Topics as unread for each user. I could create a new table with topic_id & user_id, each one being a new row but that wouldn't be good with alot of users & topics.

If somebody has a better solution I am all for it. Or can prove to me that 1 row per user_id is the best way then I'll be more than willing to do that.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at SMF (http://simplemachines.org) or any other open source PHP forum software and see how they do it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325111/check-for-value-in-mysql-row

Comment: When will people learn that normalizing their databases makes their life so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to track read messages, not the other way around. If you tracked unread messages, every time you add a user you'll have to add that user to every topics "unread list".

I looked into SMF like my comment suggested. They are using a separate table to track read messages.

A simple table that holds `user_id` and `topic_id` are you are need. When a user reads a topic, make sure there is a row in the table for that user.

Another reason to use a separate table. It's going to be faster to query against 2 int values in the database than to use `LIKE %` statements.

Comment: Alright. I really thought the CSV would be faster querying. Thank you! EDIT: I am tracking read messages.

Comment: Is it better to update the `post_id` with the newest post when the user has read the topic, then compare that `post_id` when they view the list of topics? Or to insert a row into the table when they read the topic, then when there is a new post, delete all the rows for that topic in the forum_is_read table?

Comment: I thought about it more, and I think you should track `user_id` and `topic_id`. Then do the second thing you mentioned, if a new post is added, delete all rows in `forum_is_read` for that topic_id.